# Delayed email confirmation in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, email-validation

I am using the built in email confirmation mechanism :

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password, requireConfirmationToken: true);
```

When login is performed:

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
```

The method will fail if the user has not confirmed his email yet.
I want to change this behavior so that WebSecurity.Login() will pass, and I will have the control on when to fail the login process (say, about x number of days).

Is there a way to hook up into this process ?
(It would be great if I can still use WebScurity and not revert to a lower level API).

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined process, you have to define it yourself. (WebSecurity will never send emails by itself.)

The simplest options would be to pass `requireConfirmationToken: true` as in your example and store the returned value (the confirmation token) for later. When you consider it appropriate (after x days or after following an emailed link or whatever you want) call `WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount` with the stored token. From that point on `Login` will work.

Comment: But the problem is that I want WebSecurity.Login() to pass, even if the user has yet confirmed his email.

Comment: Then simply pass `requireConfirmationToken: false` or call `WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount ` immediately after creating the account.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/backbonejs-template, it has full user registration flow that you are looking for.